# How to load image in flash with different dimensions once

Tags: flash, image

I have use the following AS2 code

```
frontLoader = new ImageLoader(object1,"fit",iWidth,iHeight);
frontLoader.loadImage(src.Url);   

frontLoader = new ImageLoader(object1,"fit",iWidth2,iHeight2);
frontLoader.loadImage(src.Url);
```

which generate 2 external calls to server, how I can load image once and use it several times in different dimensions

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Bitmap`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/display/Bitmap.html) and [`BitmapData`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/display/BitmapData.html) classes to scale your image. Load it at maximum possible resolution and then apply a suitable transform.

[Here's](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Bitmaps_03.html) the AS3 documentation on how to use these classes. It should give you a fair idea of what you can do with AS2.